# C# .Net I want to create a print class that prints datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am new in C# .Net Development. Ignore my stupidity.

-This class should be responsible for all the datagridview prints. 
-Using PrintDialog and PrintDocument.
-The code below is working perfect, is printing whatever is in the datagridview ('dataGridView_Sales' in this case), but for the current datagridview present in the current form. I now want to use this code for printing all gridviews in whichever form i want. A function should send the datagridview and the print class should accept it and make print of the datagridview sent.

Variables declared

`StringFormat strFormat; //Used to format the grid rows.
        ArrayList arrColumnLefts = new ArrayList();//Used to save left coordinates of columns
        ArrayList arrColumnWidths = new ArrayList();//Used to save column widths
        int iCellHeight = 0; //Used to get/set the datagridview cell height
        int iTotalWidth = 0; //
        int iRow = 0;//Used as counter
        bool bFirstPage = false; //Used to check whether we are printing first page
        bool bNewPage = false;// Used to check whether we are printing a new page
        int iHeaderHeight = 0; //Used for the header height`

Onclick of PrintReport Button, the datagrid view with values, prints.

`private void button_PrintReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Open the print dialog
            PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
            printDialog.Document = printDocument1;
            printDialog.UseEXDialog = true;
            //Get the document
            if (DialogResult.OK == printDialog.ShowDialog())
            {
                printDocument1.DocumentName = "Test Page Print";
                printDocument1.Print();
            }
            /*
            Note: In case you want to show the Print Preview Dialog instead of 
            Print Dialog then comment the above code and uncomment the following code
            */`

```
        //Open the print preview dialog
        //PrintPreviewDialog objPPdialog = new PrintPreviewDialog();
        //objPPdialog.Document = printDocument1;
        //objPPdialog.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void printDocument1_BeginPrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e)
    {
        int iCount = 0;
        try
        {
            StringFormat strFormat = new StringFormat();
            strFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
            strFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            strFormat.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter;

            arrColumnLefts.Clear();
            arrColumnWidths.Clear();
            iCellHeight = 0;
            iCount = 0;
            bFirstPage = true;
            bNewPage = true;

            // Calculating Total Widths
            iTotalWidth = 0;
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn dgvGridCol in dataGridView_Sales.Columns)
            {
                iTotalWidth += dgvGridCol.Width;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
          try
        {
            //Set the left margin
            int iLeftMargin = e.MarginBounds.Left;
            //Set the top margin
            int iTopMargin = e.MarginBounds.Top;
            //Whether more pages have to print or not
            bool bMorePagesToPrint = false;
            int iTmpWidth = 0;             

            //For the first page to print set the cell width and header height
            if (bFirstPage)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewColumn GridCol in  dataGridView_Sales.Columns)
                {
                    iTmpWidth = (int)(Math.Floor((double)((double)GridCol.Width /
                                   (double)iTotalWidth * (double)iTotalWidth *
                                   ((double)e.MarginBounds.Width / (double)iTotalWidth))));

                    iHeaderHeight = (int)(e.Graphics.MeasureString(GridCol.HeaderText,
                                GridCol.InheritedStyle.Font, iTmpWidth).Height) + 11;

                    // Save width and height of headres
                    arrColumnLefts.Add(iLeftMargin);
                    arrColumnWidths.Add(iTmpWidth);
                    iLeftMargin += iTmpWidth;
                }
            }
            //Loop till all the grid rows not get printed
            while (iRow <= dataGridView_Sales.Rows.Count - 1)
            {
                DataGridViewRow GridRow = dataGridView_Sales.Rows[iRow];
                //Set the cell height
                iCellHeight = GridRow.Height + 5;
                int iCount = 0;
                //Check whether the current page settings allo more rows to print
                if (iTopMargin + iCellHeight >= e.MarginBounds.Height + e.MarginBounds.Top)
                {
                    bNewPage = true;
                    bFirstPage = false;
                    bMorePagesToPrint = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (bNewPage)
                    {
                        float height = 0;
                        //Draw Header Images
                        using (var logo = Properties.Resources.logo_cptlogo)
                        {
                            e.Graphics.DrawImage(logo, e.PageBounds.Left + (e.MarginBounds.Width / 2) - (logo.Width / 2), e.MarginBounds.Top + (e.MarginBounds.Height / 2) - (logo.Height));
                            height = logo.Height ;
                        }

                        //Draw Header
                        e.Graphics.DrawString("Sales Summary", new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 12.0F, FontStyle.Bold),
                                Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds.Left, e.MarginBounds.Top -
                                e.Graphics.MeasureString("Sales Summary", new Font(dataGridView_Sales.Font,
                                FontStyle.Bold), e.MarginBounds.Width).Height + 163);

                        String strDate = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
                        //Draw Date
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(strDate, new Font(dataGridView_Sales.Font, FontStyle.Bold),
                                Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds.Left + (e.MarginBounds.Width -
                                e.Graphics.MeasureString(strDate, new Font(dataGridView_Sales.Font,
                                FontStyle.Bold), e.MarginBounds.Width).Width), e.MarginBounds.Top -
                                e.Graphics.MeasureString("Sales Summary", new Font(new Font(dataGridView_Sales.Font,
                                FontStyle.Bold), FontStyle.Bold), e.MarginBounds.Width).Height + 163);

                        //Draw Header
                        e.Graphics.DrawString("Grand Total = "+ textBox_TotalAmount.Text, new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 12.0F, FontStyle.Bold),
                                Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds.Left, e.MarginBounds.Top -
                                e.Graphics.MeasureString("Sales Summary", new Font(dataGridView_Sales.Font,
                                FontStyle.Bold), e.MarginBounds.Width).Height + 143);



                        //Draw Columns                 
                        iTopMargin = e.MarginBounds.Top + 180;
                        foreach (DataGridViewColumn GridCol in dataGridView_Sales.Columns)
                        {
                            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.LightGray),
                                new Rectangle((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount], iTopMargin,
                                (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], iHeaderHeight));

                            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black,
                                new Rectangle((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount], iTopMargin,
                                (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], iHeaderHeight));

                            e.Graphics.DrawString(GridCol.HeaderText, GridCol.InheritedStyle.Font,
                                new SolidBrush(GridCol.InheritedStyle.ForeColor),
                                new RectangleF((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount], iTopMargin,
                                (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], iHeaderHeight), strFormat);
                            iCount++;
                        }
                        bNewPage = false;
                        iTopMargin += iHeaderHeight;
                    }
                    iCount = 0;
                    //Draw Columns Contents                
                    foreach (DataGridViewCell Cel in GridRow.Cells)
                    {
                        if (Cel.Value != null)
                        {                               
                            e.Graphics.DrawString(Cel.Value.ToString(), Cel.InheritedStyle.Font,
                                        new SolidBrush(Cel.InheritedStyle.ForeColor),
                                        new RectangleF((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount], (float)iTopMargin,
                                        (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], (float)iCellHeight), strFormat);
                        }
                        //Drawing Cells Borders 
                        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, new Rectangle((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount],
                                iTopMargin, (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], iCellHeight));

                        iCount++;
                    }


                }
                iRow++;
                iTopMargin += iCellHeight;                    
            }                

            //If more lines exist, print another page.
            if (bMorePagesToPrint)
                e.HasMorePages = true;
            else
                e.HasMorePages = false;
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exc.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Please guide me what and how should i be doing and also if this is possible, which i somewhat believe it is.

Looking to enhance my c# .net skills.

Comment: Is this a trick question? Instead of referencing `dataGridView_Sales` in your code directly, reference the DataGridView you passed in.

Comment: Well i was not expecting that for an answer, my question says i want to make a class of printing and which prevents me in pasting this massive code in every form. Just make a funtion do the job by connecting to the print class. Hope you get me question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be instead of writing your own you should try the code from this codeproject page:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18042/Another-DataGridView-Printer